# Android Galaxy Tab (Honeycomb) not picking up images from any drawable

Tags: android, drawable, tablet

I have developed an application for tablets. I have checked it on two tablets of "MSI" and it was running fine. But when I run it on a Samsung Galaxy tablet (Honeycomb) it forces close on the home screen as it is not picking up images from drawable. I have tried with all types of drawable mentioned on androidDevelopers but was unable to resolve this problem.

And another thing is that at the beginning I was building my app on Windows XP and now I am using Mac OS with Windows 7. I can't understand this problem, please help me out... Thanks in advance.

[image]

here is my error log and the error is ResourcesNotFound in home screen at setContentView().
here is my code snippet

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"SqueakyChalkSound.ttf"); 

        rlCenter = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlCenter);



         try{
                InputStream ims1 = getAssets().open("iTalkFiles/background/" + "home.png");
                Drawable d1 = Drawable.createFromStream(ims1, null);
                System.out.println("image value " + ims1);

                    rlCenter.setBackgroundDrawable(d1);

                bool = false;
              }
              catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }


              if(bool == true){
                  rlCenter.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home);
                  System.out.println("image value false " );
              }


    }
```

Comment: Post the LOG from the crash and the code where it happens..

Comment: i am unable to post the LOG but i know the error. it was "resource not found exception" on setContentView(R.Layout.HomeScreen) its my first screen that comes after splash .splash is working as it is getting its image from assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

If what you wrote in your comment is not just a typo, you should replace

```
setContentView(R.Layout.HomeScreen);
```

with

```
setContentView(R.layout.HomeScreen);
```

and make sure that you have a layout xml file called HomeScreen.

Also, you cannot pick a drawable from R.layout with setContentView. You should get it from R.drawable so the way you are doing it is wrong.

Comment: i just added the image from drawable to backgroud in xml graphic view.
so when i call setContentView(R.layout.HomeScreen) the image should be visible to user but it is giving the error/

Comment: I cannot help further without seeing the whole error log and your layout xml.